# How to send data from a fragment to an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wish to send data from a fragment to an activity but my present code doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Context ctx = getActivity();
    DBoperations db = new DBoperations(ctx);
    Cursor cr = db.getInfo(db);
    cr.moveToFirst();
    long count = id;
    while( count > 0){
        cr.moveToNext();
        count --;
    }
    String ID = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(0));
    String Name = cr.getString(1);
    intent.putExtra("extra",ID + " " + Name);
    startActivity(getActivity(),LocationInfo.class);
}
```

This function is inside a class that extends Fragment.
Here the entire last line startActivity(...) is underlined in red and says:

> startActivity(android.content.intent, android.os.Bundle) in Fragment
>   cannot be applied to
>   (android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,java.lang.Class)

So how to I pass data from fragment to an activity?

Comment: I think you mean `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),LocationInfo.class))`

Comment: Yes that line only

Comment: Use the fRoStBiT's comment. You dont have new Intent written there

Comment: Read the doc to learn [how to start an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't write

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),LocationInfo.class));
```

That was the only issue...

Comment: Yes you was starting activity (calling intent) but you was not creating the intent first before using it and that was the issue! Glad you solved it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocationInfo.class);
    Context ctx = getActivity();
    DBoperations db = new DBoperations(ctx);
    Cursor cr = db.getInfo(db);
    cr.moveToFirst();
    long count = id;
    while( count > 0){
        cr.moveToNext();
        count --;
    }
    String ID = Integer.toString(cr.getInt(0));
    String Name = cr.getString(1);
    intent.putExtra("extra",ID + " " + Name);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```